# populating list in view using editorTemplates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

here is my model

```
namespace chPayroll.Models.CustInformations
{
    public class CustContact
    {
        public int cId { get; set; }
        public int cNoType { get; set; }
        public string cNo1 { get; set; }
        public string cNo2 { get; set; }
        public string cNo3 { get; set; }
        public List<CustContact> contact { get; set; }
    }
}
```

here is my editorTemplates

```
@model chPayroll.Models.CustInformations.CustContact         


@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.cNo1)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.cNo2)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.cNo3)
```

I need to show three textbox for taking email,three text box for taking telephone no. in view. how can I add the items to the list contact defined in the model so that it shows like this

```
email:--textbox1----textbox2----textbox3--
telephone:--textbox1----textbox2----textbox3--
```

and sends value to the controller

actually I am trying to send my data in list named contact here ie inside list at

```
index 0-email1-email2-email3
index 1-tel1-tel2-tel3
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your question correctly. Why do you have a nested hierarchy of classes? And have you tried this - `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.contact)` ?

Comment: I have tried @Html.EditorFor(model => model.contact) this gives me three text boxes which I will assign for emails. but how can i add another three text boxes for telephone from which I can pass value to controller

Comment: I have modified your model and added a new model in my answer below. Check if that makes sense

Comment: Take the List out of your model, it doesn't belong there.  Collect the properties (email, phone, etc...) in the controller action and then you can create and populate the list(s) there.

Comment: This is precisely what I've done in my answer. Except explicitly showing controller, assuming its very easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Sanjay: you have a strange construct in your view model:

```
public class CustContact
{
   public List<CustContact> contact;
}
```

Even if it compiles and machine understands it, I wouldn't use it as it is - *you trying to lift yourself from the ground by pulling your hair up* :)

It should be defined something along these lines (following your naming conventions & logic):

```
public class CustContact // single
{
    public int cId { get; set; }
    public int cNoType { get; set; }
    public string cNo1 { get; set; } // those are actual phones, emails etc data
    public string cNo2 { get; set; }
    public string cNo3 { get; set; }
}

public class CustContacts // plural
{
   public List<CustContact> Contacts;
}
```

View:

```
@model CustContacts
@EditorFor(m => Model)
```

Editor template:

```
@model CustContact
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.cNo1)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.cNo2)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.cNo3)
```

For brevity, we don't deal here with annotations, decorations, error handling etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: actually I was hoping to add elements in list like contact.add(cc) where cc in custContact cc

Comment: Nothing preventing you from doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment on the question, I would build the models as below

```
public class CustContact
{
    public int cId { get; set; }
    public int cNoType { get; set; }
    public string cNo1 { get; set; }
    public string cNo2 { get; set; }
    public string cNo3 { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
    public CustContact Email {get; set;}
    public CustContact Telephone {get; set;}
}
```

then create an editor template for `Customer` and in that editor template have following logic

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Telephone)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: actually I am trying to send data to list contact as above as edited the question. so please see if you can send the data from the view to the list. not making seperate classes ie using the same class but making list